# Fedora 28 - random keyboard lag

Tags: linux, fedora, freeze, lag

I have recently installed Fedora on my new Dell Vostro 5471 laptop. The installation froze at configuring user settings, so after 2 hours I have rebooted the laptop. Looked like everything was working fine, partitions were fine.

Only after reboot, when I was typing a weird lag happened. Cannot do nothing and when the lag ended the last character that was written before the lag, was written x-times (i.e. writeeeeeeeeeeee).

This problem does not repeat if the computer is up for maybe two/three hours.

Can somebody help me with this ? I will appreciate any answers.

Should I reinstall ? Maybe upgrade to 29 beta ? Is this a drivers problem ? Is there any program that will verify the integrity of my OS ?